# Solutions for noisy-in-the-rain tinned roof

Tags: metal, noise, metal-roof

Our new apartment has the peculiar problem that even light rain drops falling on the tinned/metallic roof of the balcony (pictured below) make a terrible popping noise. I normally love to keep the balcony door open and hear the sound of rain, but this is actually bothersome; I would liken it to the sound of popcorn popping (only 10x amplified), or (in heavy rain) even a machine gun!
[image]

I know there are ways to fix this if one can invest some time&money in retiling the roof etc ([example](http://callaghanroofing.com/blog/are-you-worried-about-metal-roof-noise)). But is there an easy/creative solution to this? Perhaps some material/coating that I can apply to the roof-top, that will make the rain not sound so terribly loud? The balcony roof isn't accesible particularly easily, although one can have a go through the apartment above:

[image]

Comment: I might try a foam insulation sprayed on the underside of the metal this would dampen the sound quite a bit.

Comment: If you can only access the top, perhaps a rubberized roof coating (even automotive "schutz" spray) would hold up to the elements and deaden the sound.

Comment: If it's an apartment, check that any change is acceptable to management.